# how to fix "Sliced assignment is only supported for variables for tensors"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor

I am trying to define my own custom layer in keras. In the call function, where the logic of the class lies, I am dealing with the tensor object.

After finding the maximum value from a shredded slice of a tensor object, I want to assign it to a different tensor, but I am getting ERROR

> "Sliced assignment is only supported for variables"

I have tried `Sess.eval()` in the call function of a class which does not solve the problem

```
mid_arr = x[i:spliti,j:splitj] #shredded slice
num = tf.reduce_max(mid_arr) #max vlaue from shred slice
res_arr = res_arr.assign( tf.where (res_arr[m][n],num, res_arr) ) #assign it
```

Comment: You cannot assign to tensors, because they are immutable. What you can do is create a new tensor with copied from another with some values replaced. There is no builtin operation for that at the moment, I wrote a partial more or less hacked solution [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18383#issuecomment-439459312). What do you want to replace in `res_arr`, just one element (`[m, n]`)?

Answer (score 1):

Specifying the solution here (Answer Section) even though it is present in Comments Section (thanks to jdehesa), for the **benefit of the community**.

Complete `2.x compatible code` (work around) to perform **`sliced assignment of a Tensor`** is shown below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
    
def replace_slice(input_, replacement, begin, size=None):
    inp_shape = tf.shape(input_)
    if size is None:
        size = tf.shape(replacement)
    else:
        replacement = tf.broadcast_to(replacement, size)
    padding = tf.stack([begin, inp_shape - (begin + size)], axis=1)
    replacement_pad = tf.pad(replacement, padding)
    mask = tf.pad(tf.ones_like(replacement, dtype=tf.bool), padding)
    return tf.where(mask, replacement_pad, input_)

def replace_slice_in(tensor):
    return _SliceReplacer(tensor)

class _SliceReplacer:
    def __init__(self, tensor):
        self._tensor = tensor
    def __getitem__(self, slices):
        return _SliceReplacer._Inner(self._tensor, slices)
    def with_value(self, replacement):  # Just for convenience in case you skip the indexing
        return _SliceReplacer._Inner(self._tensor, (...,)).with_value(replacement)
    class _Inner:
        def __init__(self, tensor, slices):
            self._tensor = tensor
            self._slices = slices
        def with_value(self, replacement):
            begin, size = _make_slices_begin_size(self._tensor, self._slices)
            return replace_slice(self._tensor, replacement, begin, size)

# This computes begin and size values for a set of slices
def _make_slices_begin_size(input_, slices):
    if not isinstance(slices, (tuple, list)):
        slices = (slices,)
    inp_rank = tf.rank(input_)
    inp_shape = tf.shape(input_)
    # Did we see a ellipsis already?
    before_ellipsis = True
    # Sliced dimensions
    dim_idx = []
    # Slice start points
    begins = []
    # Slice sizes
    sizes = []
    for i, s in enumerate(slices):
        if s is Ellipsis:
            if not before_ellipsis:
                raise ValueError('Cannot use more than one ellipsis in slice spec.')
            before_ellipsis = False
            continue
        if isinstance(s, slice):
            start = s.start
            stop = s.stop
            if s.step is not None:
                raise ValueError('Step value not supported.')
        else:  # Assumed to be a single integer value
            start = s
            stop = s + 1
        # Dimension this slice refers to
        i_dim = i if before_ellipsis else inp_rank - (len(slices) - i)
        dim_size = inp_shape[i_dim]
        # Default slice values
        start = start if start is not None else 0
        stop = stop if stop is not None else dim_size
        # Fix negative indices
        start = tf.cond(tf.convert_to_tensor(start >= 0), lambda: start, lambda: start + dim_size)
        stop = tf.cond(tf.convert_to_tensor(stop >= 0), lambda: stop, lambda: stop + dim_size)
        dim_idx.append([i_dim])
        begins.append(start)
        sizes.append(stop - start)
    # For empty slice specs like [...]
    if not dim_idx:
        return tf.zeros_like(inp_shape), inp_shape
    # Make full begin and size array (including omitted dimensions)
    begin_full = tf.scatter_nd(dim_idx, begins, [inp_rank])
    size_mask = tf.scatter_nd(dim_idx, tf.ones_like(sizes, dtype=tf.bool), [inp_rank])
    size_full = tf.where(size_mask,
                          tf.scatter_nd(dim_idx, sizes, [inp_rank]),
                          inp_shape)
    return begin_full, size_full

#with tf.Graph().as_default():
x = tf.reshape(tf.range(60), (4, 3, 5))
x2 = replace_slice_in(x)[:2, ..., -3:].with_value([100, 200, 300])

print('Tensor before Changing is \n', x)
print('\n')
print('Tensor after Changing is \n', x2)
```

Output of the above code is shown below:

```
Tensor before Changing is 
 tf.Tensor(
[[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
  [ 5  6  7  8  9]
  [10 11 12 13 14]]

 [[15 16 17 18 19]
  [20 21 22 23 24]
  [25 26 27 28 29]]

 [[30 31 32 33 34]
  [35 36 37 38 39]
  [40 41 42 43 44]]

 [[45 46 47 48 49]
  [50 51 52 53 54]
  [55 56 57 58 59]]], shape=(4, 3, 5), dtype=int32)


Tensor after Changing is 
 tf.Tensor(
[[[  0   1 100 200 300]
  [  5   6 100 200 300]
  [ 10  11 100 200 300]]

 [[ 15  16 100 200 300]
  [ 20  21 100 200 300]
  [ 25  26 100 200 300]]

 [[ 30  31  32  33  34]
  [ 35  36  37  38  39]
  [ 40  41  42  43  44]]

 [[ 45  46  47  48  49]
  [ 50  51  52  53  54]
  [ 55  56  57  58  59]]], shape=(4, 3, 5), dtype=int32)
```